# PyQt4 Dialog no muestra resultados según `comboBox`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Tengo una ventana `QMainWindow` con un `pushButton` que abre una segunda ventana `QDialog` y según la selección en el `comboBox` me muestra un resultado en una `label` y un `textEdit`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**llamaventana.pyw**

```
import sys

from qtdesigner.ventana import *
import qtdesigner.dialogo as dlg


class Ventana(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.btn = self.ui.pushButton

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.operaciones)

    def operaciones(self):

        self.dialogo = Dialogo(self) 
        lst_operaciones = ['Operación 1', 'Operación 2', 'Operación 3']
        self.dialogo.cbx.addItems(lst_operaciones)
        self.dialogo.cbx.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.seleccion_operaciones)
        self.dialogo.show()

    def seleccion_operaciones(self):

        seleccion_operacion = self.dialogo.cbx.currentText()

        if seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 1':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 1')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 1')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 2':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 2')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 2')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 3':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 3')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 3')

class Dialogo(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = dlg.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.cbx = self.ui.comboBox
        self.lbl = self.ui.label
        self.txt = self.ui.textEdit


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Ventana()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Para dejar el código más limpio saco el código referente a `operaciones`y `seleccion_operaciones` y lo llamo `operacion.py`.

**llamaventana2.pyw**

```
import sys

from qtdesigner.ventana import *
import qtdesigner.dialogo as dlg

from operacion import Operacion


class Ventana(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.btn = self.ui.pushButton

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.operaciones)

    def operaciones(self):

        self.dialogo = Dialogo(self) 
        Operacion(self.dialogo).seleccion_operaciones()

class Dialogo(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = dlg.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.cbx = self.ui.comboBox
        self.lbl = self.ui.label
        self.txt = self.ui.textEdit


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Ventana()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**operacion.py**

```
class Operacion:

    def __init__(self, dlg):

        self.dialogo = dlg
        lst_operaciones = ['Operación 1', 'Operación 2', 'Operación 3']
        self.dialogo.cbx.addItems(lst_operaciones)
        self.dialogo.cbx.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.seleccion_operaciones)
        self.dialogo.show()

    def seleccion_operaciones(self):

        seleccion_operacion = self.dialogo.cbx.currentText()

        if seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 1':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 1')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 1')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 2':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 2')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 2')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 3':

            self.dialogo.lbl.setText('Operación 3')
            self.dialogo.txt.setText('Operación 3')
```

Sin embargo esto no me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La selección en el `comboBox` no tiene ningún efecto en los resultados mostrados en `label` y `textEdit`.

**Editado el 29.06.2018**

Solución basada en el último párrafo del comentario del 29.06.2018 de **FJSevilla**:

**llamaventana3.py**

```
import sys

from qtdesigner.ventana import *
from dialogo3 import Dialogo


class Ventana(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.btn = self.ui.pushButton
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.operaciones)

    def operaciones(self):

        self.dialogo = Dialogo()
        self.dialogo.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Ventana()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**dialogo3.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from qtdesigner.dialogo import *


class Dialogo(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.cbx = self.ui.comboBox
        self.lbl = self.ui.label
        self.txt = self.ui.textEdit

        lst_operaciones = ['Operación 1', 'Operación 2', 'Operación 3']
        self.cbx.addItems(lst_operaciones)
        self.cbx.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.seleccion_operaciones)

    def seleccion_operaciones(self):

        seleccion_operacion = self.cbx.currentText()

        if seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 1':

            self.lbl.setText('Operación 1')
            self.txt.setText('Operación 1')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 2':

            self.lbl.setText('Operación 2')
            self.txt.setText('Operación 2')

        elif seleccion_operacion == 'Operación 3':

            self.lbl.setText('Operación 3')
            self.txt.setText('Operación 3')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Dialogo()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es muy simple en realidad pero difícil de encontrar si no se tienen en cuenta algunos conceptos clave de como se relacionan Python y C++ en PyQt y de como cada uno de ellos maneja la memoria.

El error está aquí:

```
def operaciones(self):

    self.dialogo = Dialogo(self) 
    Operacion(self.dialogo).seleccion_operaciones() # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

La causa se llama recolector de basura. Python tiene su recolector de basura que se encarga automáticamente de liberar RAM para que el SO pueda disponer de ella cuando el intérprete no la necesita más. El recolector de basura de CPython básicamente funciona contando referencias, cuando un objeto en memoria no tiene ninguna referencia asociada el GC es libre de destruirlo y liberar los recursos asociados a él.

Pues bien, tu slot `operaciones` es llamado cuando se pulsa el botón, entonces se inicia la siguiente secuencia:

1. Crea el dialogo instanciando `Dialogo`, el cual se almacena en el atributo de instancia `self.dialogo` de `myapp` (instancia de `Ventana`).
2. Después instancia `Operación` pasando el dialogo como argumento a su inicializador.
3. En el `__init__` de `Operación` se asocia la señal `currentIndexChanged` del `QComboBox` con el slot `seleccion_operaciones`.
4. Instanciada `Operación`, se llama al método de instancia  `seleccion_operaciones` del objeto creado, lo cual establece `'Operación 1'` en los tres widgets.
5. El método `operaciones` termina y retorna.

Todo parece perfecto, pero no nos olvidemos de nuestro amigo el GC, cuando hacemos `Operacion(self.dialogo).seleccion_operaciones()` y el método `seleccion_operaciones` termina, el objeto resultado de instanciar `Operación` se queda absolutamente sin referencia alguna, el GC hace su trabajo y lo manda a mejor vida, resultado: **ni siquiera existe el método de instancia `seleccion_operaciones` a partir de este momento y la señal asociada a ella queda automáticamente desconectada**.

Observase que el dialogo no desaparece porque `self.dialogo` hace referencia a la instancia de `Dialogo`, como es una variable de instancia existirá mientras `myApp` no sea destruida y el GC la deja en paz.

La solución, mantener una referencia de la instancia de `Operaciones`, no te preocupes de la de `Dialogo` ya que la instancia de `Operaciones` mantendrá una referencia a ella mediante `self.dialogo = dlg`

```
def operaciones(self):

    dialogo = Dialogo(self) 
    self.operaciones = Operacion(self.dialogo)
    self.operaciones.seleccion_operaciones()
```

Aunque lo anterior soluciona el problema, en mi opinión estás complicando demasiado las cosas y el código queda algo confuso propiciando errores como el comentado. Podrías simplemente agrupar `Operaciones` y `Dialogo` en una sola clase y moverlo a `dialogo.py` por ejemplo.

Comment: Tu solución funciona @FJSevilla, aunque me he quedado con tu comentario del último párrafo y es en lo que está basado la solución que he editado. Gracias.